# Find the fraction of Miller indices for which FCC crystals scatter

Tags: condensed-matter, scattering, crystals

I have been running into some problem (which I have essentially run down into a maths problem) with Miller indices:

I have the lattice structure factor for scattering $$S \propto \sum_{j}e^{2\pi i(hx_j+ky_j+lz_j)} $$ for Miller indices $hkl$, and where $j$ is a sum over the lattice points in the unit cell. I am then trying to find the fraction of all possible permutations of Miller indices which give rise to allowed reflections (for BCC and FCC lattices).

From the structure factor we easily derive the selection rules $h+k+l = even$ for BCC and $h, k, l $ are all either odd or even for FCC.

Then for BCC we trivially have that half of the permutations of $hkl$ give rise to reflections, but  for FCC I am struggling. I have run through a few, for example;

$\{ 001\}$ does not give reflections and has $6$ permuations, $\{011\}$ does not and has $12$ permutations, $\{111\}$ does give reflections and has $8$ permutations and so on, but I have not managed to find a clear pattern

Comment: It's just trivially 1/4. First index can be whatever you want, send two both half to be the same so 1/2*1/2 = 1/4.